# Replace with RegExp is not working

Tags: jquery, regex, performance

The .replace function is not doing anything on these RegExp.

```
(((array[0].replace("%%_%", "<ol><li>")).replace("%_%%", "</li></ol>")).replace("%_%", "<li></li>"))
```

Any help is most appreciated. (using jquery 1.6.2)

Input:

```
Ought these are balls place mrs their times add she. Taken no great widow spoke of it small. Genius use except son esteem merely her limits. %%\_%Sons park by do make on. It do oh cottage offered cottage in written%\_%Especially of dissimilar up attachment themselves by interested boisterous%\_%Linen mrs seems men table.Jennings dashwood to quitting marriage bachelor in%_%On as conviction in of appearance apartments boisterous.%\_%%
```

Output:

```
Ought these are balls place mrs their times add she. Taken no great widow spoke of it small. Genius use except son esteem merely her limits.
 1. Sons park by do make on. It do oh cottage offered cottage in written
 2. Especially of dissimilar up attachment themselves by interested
    boisterous
 3. Linen mrs seems men table. Jennings dashwood to quitting
    marriage bachelor in On as conviction in of appearance apartments
    boisterous.
```

Comment: I don't see any `regex` here

Comment: how your array is look like? why didn't you post that?

Comment: added the input and the expected output.

Comment: This is very poetic!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use regex way instead of passing a string. and make sure to use `g` global flag.

```js
var arr = ["Ought these are balls place mrs their times add she. Taken no great widow spoke of it small. Genius use except son esteem merely her limits. %%_%Sons park by do make on. It do oh cottage offered cottage in written%_%Especially of dissimilar up attachment themselves by interested boisterous%_%Linen mrs seems men table. Jennings dashwood to quitting marriage bachelor in%_%On as conviction in of appearance apartments boisterous.%_%%"];

var newArr = (((arr[0].replace(/%%_%/g, "<ol><li>")).replace(/%_%%/g, "</li></ol>")).replace(/%_%/g, "</li><li>"));

document.body.innerHTML = newArr;
```

---

Note:

You have to update this in the last `.replace`

```
.replace(/%_%/g, "</li><li>")
//----------------^^^^^^^^^----put the closing first then the opening.
```

Comment: Thanks @Jai. I don't know where i have messed up but its not happening. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: You are welcome @piyush. Just want to know how do you maintain your array?

Comment: It could not have been worse... was doing it on a wrong array. Thanks for pointing. Its working now. Thanks a ton.